# Obj loader in directX 9

Tags: indexing, directx, mesh, vertex, wavefront

I wrote a program to load an obj file in directx 9. All I do is read the vertex data and the index data from the file ( I did not read any texture or vertex normal data). Then I plug this data directly into the vertex and index buffers.

When I run the code, the objects are rendered, but they are not the correct shape. The mesh gets deformed. Here is my code -

```
D3DXCreateMeshFVF(
    index_size,  // NumFaces 
    vertex_size,  // NumVertices 
    D3DXMESH_MANAGED, // Options 
    D3DFVF_XYZ, // FVF 
    Device,  // The Device 
    &Mesh[id].MeshData);  // The Mesh 

VOID* pVertices; 
// Copy the vertices into the buffer 
Mesh[id].MeshData->LockVertexBuffer(D3DLOCK_DISCARD, (void**)&pVertices);

memcpy( pVertices, VertexData, vertex_size*sizeof(FLOAT)*3); // VertexData is the vertex data that I obtained form the obj file

// Unlock the vertex buffer 

 Mesh[id].MeshData->UnlockVertexBuffer();

// Prepare to copy the indices into the index buffer 

VOID* IndexPtr;

// Lock the index buffer

 Mesh[id].MeshData->LockIndexBuffer( 0, &IndexPtr );

// Check to make sure the index buffer can be locked 

// Copy the indices into the buffer

 memcpy( IndexPtr, IndexData, index_size*sizeof(WORD));// IndexData is the list of indices I obtained form he obj file.

// Unlock the buffer 

Mesh[id].MeshData->UnlockIndexBuffer();
```

When I display a cube, it displays only half of it, and some of the faces are missing.
I susupect it is some problem with the index buffer, but I don't know how to fix it.

I really need help.
Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont have time now to read the code, but as far as i remember, the index data in .obj files do not start on 0 but on 1, what i mean is that once you load all the index data, you should substract -1 to every index.

if you compare .OBJ with .X files you will see the difference between the index data.